# Setting KMZ layer visibility in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, layers, kmz

How do I set the visibility scale for a line KMZ created from ArcMap (Layer-to-KMZ)?

I'm sure I would have to go into the KML code and add, but add what.  That is to say as I zoom in and out using Google Earth I want certain layers to be visible and other not based upon appropriate level of visible details.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127078/setting-kmz-layer-visibility-in-arcmap/224540#comment182057_127078):

> you need to edit your kml and add in Regions with Level of Detail
>   (LOD) see
>   https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/regions#pixelrange